# Multiple messages in label

Tags: vb.net, label, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to create it so my label shows the output of each textbox but it currently only shows the last block (txtboxCat).

```
If (TxtboxS1.Text = "") Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 1 is blank"

        ElseIf IsNumeric(TxtboxS1.Text) = False Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 1 is not numeric"

        ElseIf (TxtboxS1.Text < 0 Or TxtboxS1.Text > 10) Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "score 1 is not in the range 0-10"

        ElseIf (TxtboxS1.Text > 0 Or TxtboxS1.Text < 10) Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 1 is valid"

        End If


        If (TxtboxS2.Text = "") Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 2 is blank"

        ElseIf IsNumeric(TxtboxS2.Text) = False Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 2 is not numeric"

        ElseIf (TxtboxS2.Text < 0 Or TxtboxS2.Text > 10) Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "score 2 is not in the range 0-10"

        ElseIf (TxtboxS2.Text > 0 Or TxtboxS2.Text < 10) Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 2 is valid"

        End If




        If (TxtboxS3.Text = "") Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 3 is blank"

        ElseIf IsNumeric(TxtboxS3.Text) = False Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 3 is not numeric"

        ElseIf (TxtboxS3.Text < 0 Or TxtboxS3.Text > 10) Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "score 3 is not in the range 0-10"

        ElseIf (TxtboxS3.Text > 0 Or TxtboxS3.Text < 10) Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Score 3 is valid"


        End If



        If (TxtboxCat.Text = "") Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Category is blank"

        ElseIf Not TxtboxCat.Text = "A" Or TxtboxCat.Text = "B" Or TxtboxCat.Text = "C" Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "catageory is not a valid value: A,B or C"

        ElseIf (TxtboxCat.Text = "A" Or TxtboxCat.Text = "B" Or TxtboxCat.Text = "C") Then
            LblStatusBox.Text = "Category is valid"



        End If
```

Comment: Well, as explained in the answer below it is a logical error. But before you continue I want to stress a point. **Strings are not Numbers** even when they consist only of digits. Assuming that they are the same thing, and using comparison between a Text property (a string) and a numeric constant will be a very dangerous habit that will kick you badly in future. Learn about types and correct conversions between them and Option Strict On

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because code tends to do what you've told it to do. It valiantly goes through and reassigns the value in order through your code, until it gets to the end. This reassignment **replaces the string** each time. It doesn't know you want to add it to the end, because you didn't tell it to.

Go find a string append function. Create an empty string. Everywhere you say `text = "stuff"`, replace that with the append function you find, so that you have *one big string*.

At the end, put that string into your label like you were.